# Texture paint not working Blender 2.8

Tags: texturing

I'm having troubles with texture painting. I've looked everywhere, and I cannot seem to find the solution. I follow all the basic steps and I cannot paint the texture neither in the panel nor in the 3d view.
I hope you can help me.
I attach a video of the process.
Thanks!!
https://youtu.be/W4irDFKdxiw

Comment: Try making a new image through the images editor instead

Comment: Still not working. No sensibility of the mouse in the image editor. Only "fill tool" works